# Sequentiality in a beamer: left and right part in a column and after again left

Tags: beamer, columns, pause

I would like to divide the beamer in two parts. In the left part, I would like to have text. In the right, an image.

I would like that when I show the beamer appears a part of the text of the left and the image, and after (using pause), the rest of the text of the left part.

I am using this code, but it does not work. It appears first the first part of the text, after the second part, and last the image. I would like to have the following order: the first part of the text of the left and the image, and later the second part.

This is the code I trying to do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{My Frame}
   \begin{columns}
% Column 1
\begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}

\item First part of the text
\end{itemize}
    \pause
    \begin{itemize}
          \item Second part of the text
          
    \end{itemize}
   
  
\end{column}
% Column 2    
\begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Title}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Figure.PNG}
    \end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Please, if you do not understand my problem, do not hesitate asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pause` is a very crude command. You'll get more flexibility if you use explicit beamer overlays stating on which slides your elements should be visible, e.g. `<3->` will mean that this item is shown from the 3rd slide on until the end of the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Frame}
  
  \begin{columns}
  
    % Column 1
    \begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> First part of the text
        \item<3-> Second part of the text
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    
    % Column 2    
    \begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
        \begin{uncoverenv}<2->
          \caption{Title}
          \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{uncoverenv}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    
  \end{columns}
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! thank you!

Comment: @OgeiD You're welcome!